# Unable to set background-image property

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to set the background image property. Here is the code that I am trying to use. But it raises, following uncaught exception.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div back-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530482817083-29ae4b92ff15?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1502&q=80" ></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">

app.directive('backImg', function()
{
    return function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        var url = attrs.backImg;
        element.css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + url +')',
            'background-size' : 'cover'
        });
    };
});

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> 1.html:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined
>       at 1.html:14

Comment: The tag [tag:angularjs] is for angular 1x (javascript version). Tag [tag:angular] is for https://angular.io which uses typescript and should be considered a completely different framework.

Comment: You have to define an angular application and assign it to variable `app` before you start using it. Follow along with *any* angularjs tutorial and this is the very first thing that will be covered.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `ng-app="MyApp"` to html or body tag. Then add `var app = angular.module('MyApp');` before app.directive(... .

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem. Kindly look into it again.